# MVC 3 Shared ViewModel within other views with a different Model not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on building a blog with MVC 3 and EF. I have created all my models and everything is working great. I decided I wanted to have a right nav bar with the most recent posts, comments, and all the categories. I figured this would be a good place to use a ViewModel.

I created the ViewModel using articles, comments, and categories as an icollection. I created a controller and did my linq to fill up the ViewModel and created a partial shared view. When I try to use HTML.Partial or whatnot, I get:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.Lists but expects...

The page I am using this within is a strongly typed page based on a different model.

What am I doing wrong, maybe I am just to much of a newb, or I am going about it the wrong way... help!?

**EDIT:**

The error that I get highlights the line where I call my partial view

**@HTML.Partial("_SideBar")**

SideBar uses SideBarViewModel, but my regular page that it is being called from ("Index.vbhtml") uses ArticleModel. I am not seeing how your example would work in this situation. I want to reuse this across a bunch of pages...

SideBarViewModel:

```
Public Class SidebarViewModel
    Public Property RecentPosts As ICollection(Of Article)
    Public Property RecentComments As ICollection(Of Comment)
    Public Property Categories As ICollection(Of Category)
End Class
```

ArticleModel:
    Public Class Article
        Public Property ArticleId As Integer
        Public Property Author As String

```
    <DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:D}")>
    Public Property CreatedOn As DateTime

    <DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:D}")>
    Public Property LastModified As DateTime

    Public Property Content As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Excerpt As String
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property IsPublic As Boolean

    Public Overridable Property Categories As ICollection(Of Category)
    Public Overridable Property Tags As ICollection(Of Tag)
    Public Overridable Property Comments As ICollection(Of Comment)
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your partial view you need to pass it the relevant model.

```
<% Html.renderpartial("partial", model.partialViewsModel); %>
```

So your ViewModel needs to contain a model that gets passed to the partial view and is of the type that the partial view is expecting.

So view1's model might be;

```
public class View1()
{
  public PartialModel partielViewsModel { get;set;}
  public string title {get;set;}
}
```

And view2's model might be;

```
public class View2()
{
  public PartialModel partielViewsModel { get;set;}
  public int numberofthings {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I edited my original question with my code, I am not sure how your suggestion will work when I want to use this in a bunch of pages... would I have to edit all my models?

Comment: Yes, you would have too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great solution to this problem, using a controller base class, a separate view model, and a custom filter attribute:

http://blog.bitdiff.com/2012/05/sharing-common-view-model-data-in.html